# Integrating 3rd party API with jhipster based webapp

Tags: java, api, web-applications, jhipster

I am trying to build a simple web app using jHipster. Currently I am trying to build a simple stock entity that will enable a user to input the stock name and the entity should generate a listing of that stock with open, high, low and close data. I am unable to figure out how to integrate the web app with a third party API that supplies the data. I could not find any documentation regarding this issue online. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial on implementing API's that might help.
What you need to do is create an HTTP client that can access your API.
I'm not too familiar with jHipster but finding the proper library to import seems like a good first step. Good luck.

Source:
https://zapier.com/learn/apis/chapter-8-implementation/

If you aren't sure which language to choose, a great way to narrow down the selection can be to find an API you want to implement and see if the company provides a client library. A library is code that the API owner publishes that already implements the client side of their API. Sometimes the library will be individually available for download or it will be bundled in an SDK (Software Development Kit). Using a library saves you time because instead of reading the API documentation and forming raw HTTP requests, you can simply copy and paste a few lines of code and already have a working client.